# Vapory Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, povray

I ran vapory sample code in github, but it has errors.

- Code

  ```
  from vapory import *

  camera = Camera( 'location', [0,2,-3], 'look_at', [0,1,2] )
  light = LightSource( [2,4,-3], 'color', [1,1,1] )
  sphere = Sphere( [0,1,2], 2, Texture( Pigment( 'color', [1,0,1] )))

  scene = Scene( camera, objects= [light, sphere])
  scene.render("purple_sphere.png", width=400, height=300)
  ```
- Error Message

  ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scene1.py", line 60, in <module>
  scene.render("scene1_vapory.png", width=640, height=480)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vapory\vapory.py", line 102, in render
  quality, antialiasing, remove_temp)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vapory\io.py", line 106, in render_povstring
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
  startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  ```

Comment: I don't have it. Do I have to add it?

Comment: I added the purple_sphere.png, but same error

Answer (score 2):

You first need to install POV-Ray. See [here](http://www.povray.org/download/) for the Windows binaries. 
Then, You need to change the POVRAY_BINARY variable in config.py with the actual binary path of POV-RAY installation.

1. Get the path of the executable of POV-RAY.
2. Go to C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site- 
   packages\vapory\config.py
3. Replace 
   `POVRAY_BINARY = ("povray.exe" if os.name=='nt' else "povray")`
   with 
   `POVRAY_BINARY = "POV-RAY binary path"`

the POV-RAY path will be like : **C:\Program Files\POV-Ray\v3.7\bin\pvengine.exe**

Comment: Hmm... My "config.py" for vapory places in Python path on the drive D:. I replace this string with actual path of POV-Ray but I get the same errors one-by-one as above.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 path to POV-Ray binary should be with "/" instead of "", something like that:

```
POVRAY_BINARY = "C:/Program Files/POV-Ray/v3.7/bin/pvengine.exe"
```

**INFO:** http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/11/13/things-you-can-do-with-python-and-pov-ray/